# Have Tool update info on Dockable Window

Tags: arcobjects, c#, dockable-window

When this tool is active, and a user clicks within the main map window it's getting an `IPoint` using an `IRubberPoint`.  I would like to use that point to update information on a dockable window.

*Example for simplicity*: 
For the point returned from the Tool, I would like to display the X and Y coordinates on a dockable window.

**How do I call a (non-static) dockable window function from the 'OnMouseDown' method on Tool?**

The Tool:

```
public class tlPoint : Tool
{
    public tlPoint ()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs arg)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(arg);

        IActiveView pActiveView = ArcMap.Document.ActiveView;
        IScreenDisplay3 screenDisplay = activeView.ScreenDisplay as IScreenDisplay3;
        IRubberBand rubberBand = new RubberPoint();
        IPoint point;

        point = rubberBand.TrackNew((IScreenDisplay)screenDisplay, null) as IPoint;

        // TODO: Call function on dockable window
    }

    protected override void OnUpdate()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `IDockableWindowDef.UserData` to get a reference to whatever UI control is defined in the dockable window? http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriFramework/IDockableWindowDef_UserData_Example.htm

Comment: I have not, I will look into it now and see if it does what I need.

Comment: Assuming I understand the link. I don't believe this will be useful without very creative code\event handling. I'm not just trying to update labels/Textboxes in my actual solution, I'm just using it as example for simplicity. I'm actually using the Point retrieved from the tool to run a spatial query on a mosaic dataset in order to find the raster who's counterpoint is closest to the Point, and displaying it on a AxMapContol on the Dockable window. I can add this to the question, but wasn't sure if it was relevant and didn't want to over complicate it.

Comment: Note that's a very old link.  Since then add-ins now support Dockable windows. The strategy for those is a bit different.

Comment: I am using an Add-In component Dockable window, in an ArcMap Add-in project.

Comment: See https://geonet.esri.com/thread/56498

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, if you summarize that thread for the "For a dockable window AddIn:" in an answer I'll accept it. -Thank you